# Bad mathchar (79119) using htlatex+mathml with \uparrow with align from amsmath package

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, mathml

texlive 2012 debian package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{document}  
\begin{align}
      &    \uparrow\sum F
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

compile with

```
htlatex report.tex "htm,mathml" " -cunihtf"
```

gives

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/html-mml.4ht) 
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) 
(./report.aux) 
! Bad mathchar (79119). <argument>  & \uparrow \sum F 
                               l.8 \end{align}
                ?
```

But when compile as

```
 htlatex report.tex "htm,xhtml" " -cunihtf"
```

or

```
 htlatex report.tex "htm" " -cunihtf"
```

No error.

What should I do? Is this a bug in htlatex? any workaround? 
The problem happens when using `\uparrow` with mathml and when using `align`. Without `align` there is no error.

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{document}  
    $\uparrow\sum F$
\end{document}
```

Now

```
  htlatex report.tex "htm,mathml" " -cunihtf"
```

No error.

**update**

fyi, if you are using htlatex with `mathml` watch out for `align`.  Workaround I found for now is to use `eqnarray`. Now the errors went away.  I am trying to compile to HTML code generated by Scientific word, which generated the `align` Latex code. So I had to edit the code and change all the `align` to `eqnarray` as temporary fix for now to get HTML generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time, but I think to have found the issue. In several places of `mathltx.4ht` there are `\mathchar"<number>` without a space at the end.

In particular the problem seems to be in line 1142:

```
1141 \def\:tempd#1#2{%
1142    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\mathchar"13#2}%
1143    \MathSymbol\mathop{#1}%
1144    \expandafter\def\csname #1:limits\endcsname{\expandafter
1145                     \:same \math:sym\mathop{#1}\limits}%
1146    \expandafter\def\csname #1:nolimits\endcsname{\expandafter
1147                   \:same \math:sym\mathop{#1}\nolimits}%
1148    \expandafter\edef\csname n:#1:\endcsname{\noexpand\ifDisplayMath
1149           \noexpand\expandafter \expandafter\noexpand
1150                                         \csname #1:limits\endcsname
1151           \noexpand\else \noexpand\expandafter
1152                          \expandafter\noexpand
1153                          \csname #1:nolimits\endcsname\noexpand\fi}%
1154    \expandafter\pend:def\csname n:#1:\endcsname{\ifDisplayMath
1155           \mathop:prefix{mathsize="big"}\fi}%
1156 }
```

What happens is that `\sum` is redefined and at the end `\o:sum:` is expanded to

```
\mathchar"1350
```

Now the `F` just after it makes TeX add it to the number, because `F` is a proper hexadecimal digit. And `0x1350F` represents exactly the number 79119.

Solution: make the bug known to the maintainers; the line should be

```
1142    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\mathchar"13#2\relax}%
```

In the interim you can add this to your preamble:

```
\documentclass[]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifcsname o:sum:\endcsname
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname o:sum:\endcsname{\relax}
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
      &    \uparrow \sum F
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

but the problem might present also for other operators, for instance `\bigcup`: only when a hexadecimal digit follows (they are `0123456789ABCDEF`).

Comment: I've submitted bug report, together with a patch: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?230 thank you for localising the issue